# Como desfazer 'Discart All Changes' do Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

No Visual Studio Code, na "Aba Sourse Control: GIT" em "Discart All Changes" apagou as alterações feitas e alguns arquivos que criei. 
Existe uma forma de reverter isso e recuperar os arquivos deletados?

Comment: Esses arquivos já estavam commitados?

Comment: Não estavam @Felipe Avelar

Comment: Vc já tinha dado `. add` ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Não fiz nenhuma ação de git @hugocsl, somente programei os arquivos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mudanças que não foram *commitadas*  não podem ser recuperadas, pois nunca foram "rastreadas" pelo git, logo, infelizmente, ele não tem um *snapshot* com essas mudanças.

Caso você tenha algum plugin no vs code que veja o histórico local, como é o caso do [local history](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz.local-history), você pode recuperar os arquivos pelo histórico de edição.

Comment: Suspeitava que essa seria a resposta correta. Tudo que eu li, inclusive, reforça a ideia de que o git não mantém "_unstaged changes_". Achei, inslusive, [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25792257/4438007) no SO internacional que reforça que não há mais esperança